# Forecast of IMA(1,1) process using SES

Tags: time-series, forecasting

When a time series follows an IMA(1,1) process and single exponential smoothing (SES) is used as a forecasting method, should we select a low smoothing constant ($\alpha<0.3$) or a larger one ($\alpha>0.5$)? What is the intuitive interpretation?

Comment: What's a 'deman' series? And is there anything special about values of 0.3 or 0.5 for the smoothing constant?

Comment: demand time series, I'm thinking if we should use higher smoothing constant for non-stationary series more than 0.5

Comment: Estimate it from the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate it from your IMA model. If your time series with moving average parameter $\theta$ is given by

$Y_t = Y_{t-1} +\epsilon - \theta\epsilon_{t-1}$

(where $\epsilon_t$ is the innovation at $t$, & the innovations are Normally i.i.d.) then the one-step ahead forecast is

$\hat{Y}_t(1) = (1-\theta)Y_t+(1-\theta)\theta Y_{t-1}+(1-\theta)\theta^2 Y_{t-2}+\ldots$

from which you get the updating equation

$\hat{Y}_t(1) = (1-\theta)Y_t+\theta\hat{Y}_{t-1}(1)$

So $\alpha=1-\theta$

Higher values of $\alpha$ pull the forecast more strongly towards recent observed values.

Comment: Thank you, actually α=1−θ is a optimal smoothing constant valueright, my question is when the demand process is non-stationary , can we use small smoothing constant(α<0.3) because we say the small value of alpha is better for stationary process.

Comment: @Roji, If your demand process is IMA(1,1) then it *is* non-stationary.

Comment: Yes I know, but the question is for non-statiorary process which one is better, (α<0.3) or α>0.5? what I'd like to know is the intuitive inference not consdering calculation.

Comment: Well take IMA(1,1) as an example of a non-stationary process. The MA parameter $\theta$ can take values between 1 & -1, so the best values of $\alpha$ can be between 0 & 2 (though for $\alpha\geq 1$ it's no longer really 'smoothing').

Comment: For an intuitive way to guess $\alpha$, remember that lower values of $\alpha$ smooth more, & that more jagged series need more smoothing. Plotting graphs of forecasts versus actuals for different values of $\alpha$ can give a good idea.